# ReferenceError: Dato is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy realizando una aplicación con **angularjs 1.6**, consiste en hacer una consulta a un **servicio REST** que devuelve un arreglo de clientes, estos datos quiero colocarlos en un arreglo de Objetos, sin embargo en el momento de crear el new cliente, se presenta el error que no esta definido.

este es mi **objeto**

```
function Cliente(datos){
this.idCliente = datos.idCliente;
this.idCiudad = datos.idCiudad;
this.nombreCliente = datos.nombreCliente;
this.nit =  datos.nit;
this.direccion = datos.direccion;
this.telefono = datos.telefono;
this.email = datos.email;
this.nombreCompletoContacto = datos.nombreCompletoContacto;
this.telefonoContacto = datos.telefonoContacto;
this.fechaCreacion = datos.fechaCreacion;
this.estado = datos.estado;
this.muestraMandatorio = datos.muestraMandatorio;
this.mostrarLogoCliente = datos.mostrarLogoCliente;
this.fechaIngreso = datos.fechaIngreso;}
```

el siguiente es el **servicio**

```
app.service("servicioClientes", function($http, $location){
this.listaClientes = function(){
    var url = $location.protocol() + "://"+$location.host() + ":" + $location.port() + "/url/servicio/REST";
    var config = {headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'}}
    console.log("Realizando request a " + url);
    return $http.get(url, config);
}}).service("conversorObjetos", function(){
this.convertirClientes = function(listJsonClientes){
    var listaObjetosClientes = [];
    for(var i=0; i<listJsonClientes.length;i++){
        listaObjetosClientes.push(new Cliente(listJsonClientes[i]));
    }
    return listaObjetosClientes;
}});
```

El siguiente es el **controlador**

```
app.controller("controladorClientes", 
function($scope, $http, $window, servicioClientes, conversorObjetos, $location){

    $scope.nuevoCliente = {};

    var peticion = servicioClientes.listaClientes();

    peticion.then(function(response){
        if(response.data){

            $scope.listaClientes = conversorObjetos.convertirClientes(response.data);

        }else{
            console.log("response data empty");
        }
    });
});
```

Este es el orden de **carga de los objetos**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controladores/clienteController.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/objetos/cliente.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/servicios/clienteServices.js"</script>
```

Cuando estoy en la página que presenta el error, y valido los objetos cargados encuentro el controlador y el servicio, pero no el objeto cliente.js.

este es el **error** que se presenta

> ReferenceError: Cliente is not defined at Object.convertirClientes

Agradezco de su colaboración, soy nuevo en esto y si hay sugerencias adicionales se agradecen.

Comment: ¿Tienes todas las referencias bien? He estado probandolo y no me saltan errores excepto el REST que no esta hubicado donde ami me indica claro.

Comment: No tienes la funcion `Cliente` dentro de una funcion anonima o algo asi? Me funciona perfectamente a mi tambien.

Comment: Gracias por sus respuetas, @GDP no se a que te refieres por referencias, si esto corresponde a las etiquetas en el index.html si, ya valide las rutas y los nombres y todo esta bien.

Comment: @Einer soy nuevo con js y el concepto de función anomina no me es muy claro, la función Cliente esta dentro de un archivo llamado cliente.js y es lo único que contiene.